# Are there any security advantages of using the command line over a GUI?

Tags: command-line, security, gui

Are there any security advantages of using the command line over a GUI?

Or any other advantages?

Comment: The `any other advantages` part makes the question a bit too broad. Keep questions specific and narrow. I'd suggest removing that bit

Answer (score 1):

As far as X11 server goes (which is one of the GUI implementations for *nix systems), one of very famous disadvantages of using that is clipboard - virtually any application can access it and add data to it, which means if you have sensitive data in clipboard, any application can steal it. Conversely, there are ways to [masquerade malicious commands](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39118/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-this-kind-of-clipboard-abuse) as harmless. Now, take a naive and inexperienced junior sysadmin, that copies commands from the web into terminal on production server, and they copy one of malicious commands into it. The boss can be very happy about it :)

There are [methods to mitigate it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421184/85039), and  [Wayland display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) strives to solve this as one of the issues.Now compare that with command-line - there's no access to clipboard. So among many things, that's at least one advantage.

Tangentially, having no GUI [reduces attack surface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195229/85039) and minimizes complexity of the system, thus the easier it's to administer and the more minimalist a system is, the better it can be considered security-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the CLI is you can get more done faster once you know where things are and what they do.

The advantage of the GUI is you can explore where things are and accomplish tasks with little or none technical knowledge.

A well rounded person would use both CLI and GUI throughout their day IMO.

Comment: "A well rounded person would use both CLI and GUI throughout their day IMO."  Hehe, depends on the context in which a well-rounded person works, IMHO.  In private setting or where data isn't immediately accessible from the internet - then both GUI and CLI is fine, but on a server which can be under attack at any moment, GUI might not be that desirable.  But yes, I whole heartedly agree - well-rounded person should use both